# How to construct and pass bson document - Go lang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using [Go](http://golang.org/) and mongoDB in my project and  [mgo](http://labix.org/mgo) is to connect  to connect `MongoDB`.

I am having following document this is to be inserted in the MongoDB

```
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("53439d6b89e4d7ca240668e5"),
     "balanceamount" : 3,
     "type" : "reg",
     "authentication" : {
       "authmode" : "10",
       "authval" : "sd",
       "recovery" : {
          "mobile" : "sdfsd",
          "email" : "sds@gmail.com"
        }
      },
     "stamps" : {
        "in" : "x",
        "up" : "y"
     }
  }
```

I have created the BSON document as above.

I have two packages

1. account.go
2. dbEngine.go

**account.go** is used to create BSON document and send the BSON document to dbEngine.go

**dbEngine.go** is used to establish connection to MongoDB and insert the document.
while passing BSON document to dbEngine.go

dbEngine.Insert(bsonDocument);

In dbEngine.go i am having method

```
func Insert(document interface{}){
 //stuff
}
```

> **Error :** panic: Can't marshal interface {} as a BSON document.

Whether interface{} is not to be used for BSON document.

I am new to `Go`. Any suggestion or help will be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate a BSON document yourself.
Let say in account.go you will have an account struct:

```
type Account struct {
  Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"` // import "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
  BalanceAmount int
  // Other field
}
```

Then in dbEngine.go your Insert function:

```
func Insert(document interface{}){
  session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
  // check error
  c := session.DB("db_name").C("collection_name")
  err := c.Insert(document)
}
```

And then, some where in your app:

```
acc := Account{}
acc.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
acc.BalanceAmount = 3

dbEngine.Insert(&acc);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mgo` driver uses the [`labix.org/v2/mgo/bson`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson) package to handle BSON encoding/decoding.  For the most part, this package is modelled after the standard library `encoding/json` package.

So you can use structs and arrays to represent objects.  For example,

```
type Document struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    BalanceAmount int `bson:"balanceamount"`
    Type string `bson:"type"`
    Authentication Authentication `bson:"authentication"`
    Stamps Stamps `bson:"stamps"`
}
type Authentication struct {
    ...
}
type Stamps struct {
    ...
}
```

You can now create values of this type to pass to `mgo`.