# Can't marshal string as a BSON document error in Golang mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to read some data from MongoDB in go using **gopkg.in/mgo.v2** driver. i have written the following code to extract the information form MongoDB.

my go struct

```
type NetworkUser struct {
    Id         bson.ObjectId   `bson:"_id,omitempty"        json:"-"`
    FirstName  string          `bson:"firstName"            json:"firstName"`
    MiddleName string          `bson:"middleName,omitempty" json:"middleName,omitempty"`
    LastName   string          `bson:"lastName"             json:"lastName"`
    Inserted   time.Time       `bson:"inserted"             json:"-"`
}
```

then, i have written the following code for reading from the mongo

```
//Connect to the Collection and Execute query
_collection := _session.DB(database).C(collection)

//Executing the query 
var results []NetworkUser
err = _collection.Find(query).All(&results)

//Handle the errors
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    panic(err)
}
```

When i run the code, i am getting the following error : **Can't marshal string as a BSON document**

Please let me know, if anyone come across this error and how to fix it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930060/how-to-construct-and-pass-bson-document-go-lang

Comment: Try removing the JSON export. You don't need to cast mongo data to json, leave in as a bson.